# ionic ion-nav-title not updating

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

My problem is that, despite using `ion-nav-title` my nav bar title **isn't updating** when *coming from a child state* from `ui-sref`.

But the nav bar **updates fine** when *coming from a parent state*.

I've followed this tutorial to improve the default Slide Menu example: http://robferguson.org/2015/01/07/ionics-sidemenu-template-and-nested-states/

Now my back button is a custom one

```
<ion-nav-buttons side="left">
    <button class="button button-icon button-clear" ui-sref="app.events.detail.subevents({eventId : eventDetails._id})">
        <i class="icon ion-arrow-left-c"></i>
    </button>
</ion-nav-buttons>

<ion-nav-title>
    <span ng-bind="subEventDetails.eventTitle"></span>: Participants
</ion-nav-title>
```

Here's a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/jI3iD64apMJLTwaboSkm?p=preview) to show my issue. It demoes 3 level of nested view; Event, Sub Events, Participants.

Scenario:

1. slide menu; Events
2. Title shows "List of Events", the title is correct
3. pick event 1 to see its sub events
4. Title shows "Event 1: List of sub events", the title is updated correctly
5. pick sub event 1
6. Title shows "SubEvent 1: List of Participants", the title is updated correctly
7. **Go Back and the title will not change**, it should revert back to "Event 1: List of sub events" but shows "SubEvent 1: List of Participants" instead. Note that the sub Events are displayed nevertheless...

Also, the problem doesn't happen when going back from step 3, because I'm not using a dynamic `ion-nav-title` but a static `ion-view title`.

Hope someone has come accros this problem before, before I need the title to be dynamic.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

answer from Ionic Forum http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-ion-nav-title-not-updating/30731

The **solution is to disable cache on the abstract views**, responsible for the Tabs views.